# Sparql: getting all politicians who ruled a city

Tags: sparql

I'm new to sparql and I'm trying to understand how to get the resources I need for building a query. I started trying to get all the politicians that ruled a city or a country, and at the moment I could do just the following:

I started by following the links in snorql (in the prefixes) and looking for an entity by adding "politician" at the end. I found one :

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
```

So I wrote **http://dbpedia.org/resource/Politician** and the resource does exist. I tryed to use it in this way:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT ?thing WHERE { 
   ?thing a :Politician .
   ?thing dbo:birthPlace dbpedia:Italy.
}
LIMIT 50
```

[Run in virtuoso](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpedia%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fthing%20WHERE%20%7B%20%0D%0A%3Fthing%20a%20dbo%3APerson.%0D%0A%3Fthing%20dbo%3AbirthPlace%20dbpedia%3AItaly.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%2050).

Even if I remove the second line of the `SELECT`, I have no results. But if I change the first line with: `?thing a dbo:Person`. or even if I remove it, I get the people born in Italy. But not just the politicians. A second problem is I don't need the politicians that were born but ruled that place. How or where can I find that kind of "relations/descriptors"? Now I am just googling and copy-pasting some existing examples, but I would like to understand how to look for more specific things.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question. What exactly you would like to do?

Comment: @aquiros to get 50 politicians that ruled Italy. No matter the time, just that

Comment: the problem is xhen i add ?thing a :Politician I have no results

Comment: That specific problem is because Politician is part of `dbo` prefix and not the default prefix. Try with `a dbo:Politician`.

Comment: yes, it worked. and a second problem is i don't want the politicians born in Italy, just the ones that ruled Italy (i know, this has more sense for a region)

Comment: I can't find a relation for "ruled" or something like that. Do you know the specific relation you are looking for?

Comment: Would it work for you to list all people with the title "Prime minister of Italy"?

Comment: @aquiros I mean, all politicians that belong to a city. But one thing is borning in a city and another one is ruling or governing a city. For example, a politician could born in Italy but rule in France. In that case, I want to filter that guy, because he ruled another country not Italy

Comment: What I am looking is a value for "?ruled": ?thing ?ruled dbpedia:Italy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118542/discussion-between-aquiros-and-gal007).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first query isn't working because `Politician` is not part of the default (`:`) namespace, but instead it is present in DBpedia Ontology namespace (`dbo`).

So, your query should be:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT ?thing WHERE { 
   ?thing a dbo:Politician .
   ?thing dbo:birthPlace dbpedia:Italy.
}
LIMIT 50
```

To list all politician who ruled Italy you would need to know which is the predicate for "ruled". Once you have it you can construct a query.

To list all predicates present in the database you can write something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT(?b) WHERE { 
?a ?b ?c.
}
```

And it will list all predicates.

I would recommend you to browse through one or two politician and see the predicates they have to check if one works for you.